# a linear layout does not seems straight

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Linear Layout but somehow, no matter what, the login button dose not sits exactly below the text fields. the button always exceeds from the elements.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
     >



      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:contentDescription="@string/AppLogDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/applogo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:layout_width="272dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail_icon"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/mail_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/password_icon"
             android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:drawablePadding="5dp"
               android:padding="10dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/LogInButton"
                android:layout_width="284dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/LogIn"
                android:onClick="LogInClickEvent" />

        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1">




                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/cb_login"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:onClick="RememberMe_click"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn=""
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:checked="false" />
                       <TextView
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="Remember me"
                           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                           android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                           android:layout_weight="0.70" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/TV_LogIn"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="23dp"
                    android:text="Forget Password?"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:onClick="ForgetPasswordEvent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout >
</ScrollView>
```

My text fields seems straight but the buttons (login button and remember me switch) seem to be off grid and a bit more to the right then the fields

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are seeing?

Comment: your `LinearLayout` is missing the end tag.  can you post a more complete version of your xml layout?

Comment: I have an end tag. I can't post an image because my rep is below 10. Iv'e added the full xml right now

Answer (score 0):

Remove your android:padding="10dp" from your second edittext
and android:layout_marginTop="10dp from your button.

And make sure your linearlayout orientation is vertical.

**EDIT**: 
you should use layout_gravity="center" instead of android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" which are for RelativeLayout 
or put your linearLayout inside a RelativeLayout which should be your root layout.

Comment: That didn't fixed the problem. Just made the button stick to the text box. My elements don't seem to be on the same grid.

Comment: Sorry, but my login button never seems to fit the othes fields. it seems like this button isn't filling the place it should.

Comment: can you post a screenshot with indicators of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can't. must be reputation 10 or above

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_email"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail_icon"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/mail_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_Password"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogInButton"
        android:layout_width="261dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/LogIn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="LogInClickEvent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

This will not work if you want to put everything on bottom:

```
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Because it is for **RelativeLayout** and not for LinearLayout.

Comment: I've tried it and now all the fields are attached to the left side of the screen and still, the login button and the remember me switch seems to be a bit off the grid and a bit far from the others (they seem a bit more to the right)